# Django aggregation: Sales by Category

Tags: django, aggregation

i'm trying to get a total of sales by category.

I know there is a way to do this with python, but i would rather do it with querys or aggregation.

My models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   category= models.ForeignKey(Category)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Store(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Sale(models.Model):
   item=models.ForeignKey(Item)
   store=models.ForeignKey(Store)
   quantity=models.IntegerField()

class Store_Item(models.Model):
   item=models.ForeignKey(Item)
   store=models.ForeignKey(Store)
   price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

The result should be something like this:

```
          sales total
books     100   859.10
audio     200   1894.20

total     300   2753.3
```

Right now i'm getting the total quantity of every category like this:

```
p=Sale.objects.all().values('item__category__name').order_by('item__category__name').annotate(total=Sum('quantity'))
```

I get:

```
books  100
audio  200
```

But i'm stuck in the prices part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to get all sales by Category like this:

test=Sale.objects.all().order_by('item__category').annotate(total=Sum('quuantity')).values('item__category__name', 'total')

I already search here, and i'm still searching

Comment: You should update your question showing what you have been trying, your current output, errors, etc. You need to make this easier so the rest can help you out

Comment: Thanks César, i already got the sum of every category. I'm stuck in the select from the prices of the item in every store.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a function to your model. Something like this should work.

```
class Sale(models.Model):
   item=models.ForeignKey(Item)
   store=models.ForeignKey(Store)
   quantity=models.IntegerField()

   def _getTotal(self):
     self.sale.extra(select=("total": "quantity * item_price")
                                ).aggregate(total=Sum("total"))["total"]
```

Comment: I'm saving the prices in Store_Item